# How to create &larr; in XAML

Tags: xaml

How to create `&larr;` (←) in XAML? I want to create backspace button.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If directly entering `←` does not work, try

```
&#x2190;
```

Answer (score 1):

I am certain there must be a better way than this, but you can just use the special character directly in the xaml.

I was able to cut and paste a back arrow into the content of a text block and it displayed correctly.

```
    <TextBlock Height="23" Width=20 HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="textBlock1" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" >
        ←
    </TextBlock>
```

So you should be able to use that text block as part of the template for a control.

I'm not sure exactly what you need, but I think it would give a better effect to use an image for the back arrow instead of using text.

Answer (score 1):

The encoding of the files are UTF-8 so you can just write in the arrow right in the file.

e.g.,

```
<Label>←</Label>
<Label Content="←" />
```

Comment: Nitpick: the encoding is UTF-8 unless there is an XML declaration stating some other encoding.